# How to make all input forms 100% width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, width, form-control

I have tried different approaches to make all input forms the same width and let them all end at 100%, but it doesn't work with the constellation below. Does anybody have an idea how to implement the idea?

```html
<form action="" method="post">
                                                    
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Card Number" data-securionpay="number" />
  </div>
                                                  
  <div class="form-group" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 32%" placeholder="CVC"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 21%" placeholder="MM"/>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 42%" placeholder="YYYY"/>
  </div>
                                                  
  <button style="width: 100%" type="submit">Pay</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need:

```
.form-group {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Because now div separate your sections with new space, but if you use "inline block", then your every div will be close. This should do input near input in one line.

Answer (score 1):

All your elements are not full width because you define some of the elements to have other width value for instance your defined rule on the input to be 42%,
if you want every to be full width then you should remove all the inline css style with property width define to with less than 100%.

Remove this style="width: 21%", style="width: 42%", from your input fields.

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Card Number" data-securionpay="number" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="CVC"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="MM"/>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="YYYY"/>
  </div>

  <button style="width: 100%" type="submit">Pay</button>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this may be this is want you want to achieve

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Card Number" data-securionpay="number" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 32%; float: left" placeholder="CVC"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 21%; float: left" placeholder="MM"/>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 42%; float: left" placeholder="YYYY"/>
  </div>

  <button style="width: 100%" type="submit">Pay</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This works, if the last ` float` is `float: right`, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So one option for you to explore would be the `input-group` class that is part of Bootstrap's CSS for Forms.  This allows you to group multiple form elements into a single row and it will distribute the widths for you automatically.

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="post">
                                                    
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Card Number" data-securionpay="number" />
</div>
                                                  
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" placeholder="CVC"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MM"/>
    <div class="input-group-append input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">/</span></div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="YYYY"/>
  </div>
</div>
                                                  
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary">Pay</button>
</form>
```

An advantage to this method (as it relates back to using Bootstrap in the first place) is that you're not relying on inline styles.  If you review the above code you'll see a variety of Bootstrap utility classes (like `.mr-2`) for positioning elements, or converting your submit button into a block element, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hi) Here is an amazing 100% adaptive form solution:

```css
.form-block {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-block form {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-block form input {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.form-block form textarea {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-block">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Article</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Description</label>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <button>Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```